# Eclipse Preference Page Overwrite Restore Defaults Button Listener

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I am working on a eclipse plugin that has a preference page, and I was wondering if I could have the possibility to find the "Restore Defaults" button and overwrite it's listener, because I have to setup a program's variable when the button is pushed(I have to get a preference store variable value and save it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override the `performDefaults` method.

```
@Override
protected void performDefaults() {
    super.performDefaults();

    // TODO your code
}
```

Comment: Momentarily I do not have any class that implements `PreferencePage`. Can I make an existing class implement this interface and then override it? Also, will it get called remotely by the button, since I cannot know when it will be pressed?

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. What class are you extending?

Comment: Let's say I overwritten this method, when it's going to be called?